# pkg-config unable to locate pangoft2 and gstreamer

Tags: linux, debian, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, pango

I installed pangoft2 on my debian with the command  `$ sudo apt install build-essential libpangoft2-1.0.0` and installed gstreamer with  `$ sudo apt install build-essential gstreamer1.0-plugins-*`
they were both successfulyy installed but pkg-config is unable to locate them.
i can't even find them with `whereis`.

Answer (score 1):

.pc files are distributed as part of dev packages. In your case I think you are looking to install libpango1.0-dev package.